# Minecraft 1.13 colored names on items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.13, there is a way to make bold and italic and colored names on items. I have figured this out, and done this:

```
/give @p minecraft:golden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"GoldenHeart Blade\",\"color\":\"gold\",\"italic\":\"false\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"}}
```

This works like a charm. Howevever, what I want is multiple colors in one name. To have multiple text strings, like is possible in /tellraw. I tried this:

```
/give @p minecraft:golden_sword{display:{Name:"\"text\":\"GoldenHeart\",\"color\":\"gold\",\"italic\":\"false\",\"bold\":\"true\"},{\"text\":\" Blade \",\"color\":\"white\",\"italic\":\"false\",\"bold\":\"true\}"}}
```

This would, in an ideal world, make "Blade" of "GoldenHeart Blade" white instead of gold like "GoldenHeart" is. Instead, it only gave me a golden text "GoldenHeart". Is there a way to have multiple text strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like with `/tellraw`, you'll need to put the components in square brackets (`[` `]`) to make it a list:

```
[
    {
        "text": "GoldenHeart ",
        "color": "gold",
        "italic": false,
        "bold": true
    },
    {
        "text": "Blade",
        "color": "white",
        "italic": false,
        "bold": true
    }
]
```

Escaped and in the command:

```
/give @p minecraft:golden_sword{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"GoldenHeart\",\"color\":\"gold\",\"italic\":false,\"bold\":true},{\"text\":\" Blade\",\"color\":\"white\",\"italic\":false,\"bold\":true}]"}}
```